# Opinion.. getting taxonomy 'name' label efficiently in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-taxonomy

I'd like ideas for the quickest/shortest/best ways to echo a taxonomy's 'name' label in Wordpress.

I have this tax:

```
function register_tax_service() {
    $labels = array( 
        'name' => _x( 'Services', 'service' ),
    //ect etc
}
```

So if I do this inside the taxonomy.php template it works:

```
$full_tax = get_taxonomy(get_query_var('taxonomy'));
echo $full_tax->labels->name;
```

Is that a good way to do it? Getting the whole tax object just for one string seems a bit much! I've had a good look around and there are plenty of ways to get the tex slug, but I couldn't find another way to get the label.

Thanks!
Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ben this is the way it usually works, i suppose. If you are doing this not inside a loop or somthing like that, I think the overhead is not that big, neither the object is (it consists of about 14 fields).

However, there is a way to get just the taxonomy name directly from the database. This is the way to go anytime, when the WordPress function reference is not enough for the things you want to query, for example (not tested!):

```
global $wpdb;
$taxname = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT name FROM $wpdb->terms WHERE slug='".$wpdb->escape(get_query_var('taxonomy')."');
```

Use the [WordPress Database description](http://codex.wordpress.org/images/9/9e/WP3.0-ERD.png) for unusual queries.

But I do not think you will have a large benefit in performance when doing this.

Comment: Thanks! That's really useful to know about the $wpdb object, I think I'll be using that a lot!